# How can I divide the frequency found from two different summarise function in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, stat

How can I divide the frequency found from two different summaries?

The code of first summary :

```
brfss2013 %>% 
  filter( !is.na(income2), Depression == "SignsOfDepression") %>% 
  group_by(X_state) %>%  
   summarise(depressed=n())
```

[Depressed frequency state wise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiiAy.png)

The code of second summary:

```
brfss2013 %>% 
  filter( !is.na(income2)) %>% 
  group_by(X_state) %>%  
   summarise(total=n())
```

[total frequency state wise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM7Ig.png)

Now I want to find the relative frequency of "depressed" and "total" state-wise where I divide "depressed"/ "total".

I tried to use the following code:

```
 brfss2013 %>% 
  filter( !is.na(income2)) %>% 
  group_by(X_state) %>%
   summarise(ratio = depressed/total)
```

But it does not work.

Can somebody please help me to find the state-wise relative frequency.

Answer (score 2):

```
brfss2013 %>% 
  filter( !is.na(income2) ) %>% 
  group_by(X_state) %>%  
  summarise(depressed=sum(Depression == "SignsOfDepression"), total=n()) %>%
  mutate(ratio=depressed/total)
```

Comment: When I use the code above the SignsOfDepression from the Depression Variable does not get counted. The total gets counted, however, the depressed is shown as NA. Can you please tell me how can I count the number of times the SignsOfDepression occurred and then divide it by the total count.

Comment: I'm not sure i can help you further. the code i wrote looks correct. however, you did not provide a reproducible example of your data structure, `brfss2013`, so i can't be sure.

Comment: Thank you Langtang! The codes you provided worked, earlier I had not filtered the NA values from the Depression variable therefore it was not working. Again Thanks a lot for your help! :)